# `nums[nums.length - 1]; ` is an range or single element?

Tags: java

I read such a solution to rotate an array

the question:

```
public class Solution {
    public void rotate(int[] nums, int k) {
        int temp, previous;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            previous = nums[nums.length - 1];
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
                temp = nums[j];
                nums[j] = previous;
                previous = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am confused about `previous = nums[num.lengh -1]`,
is it a range as `nums[0:10]` or a single element as `nums[0]`?

Comment: It is a single element, because `num.lengh -1` just gives you the last accessible index of the array.

Comment: oh, thank you, I got it, constantly swap the current and previous, could you please transmit the comment to answer @deHaar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a single element, because `num.lengh - 1` is an `int` and just gives you the last accessible index of the array.

If you check wether the length of the array is `> 0`, then you can safely use the length of the array to determine the last accessible index.

The length of an array is very often used in loops like yours:

Here the length is used to make sure you don't access unavailable indexes:

```
for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++)
```

You can write slightly a different condition without changing the functionality

```
for (int j = 0; j <= nums.length - 1; j++)
```

But if you do the following, you will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= nums.length; j++)
```

The last iteration would try to access nums[nums.length], which isn't there...

Answer (score 3):

It's a single element, he is taking the element in the `num.length -1` position, and the value inside is being swapped with `nums[j]`:
for `j=0` you have:

```
temp = num[0];
num[0] = num[num.length-1]
num[num.length-1] = temp;
```

And so on.

Answer (score 2):

`nums[nums.length - 1];` gives you the last position of the array. It is -1 cause the positions of an array starts with 0 not with 1.

If you don't write -1 you would get an Out of bounds exception.

Comment: How about `nums[-1]`, I thougth this slicing can retrieve the last element in an easy way.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. you would get an exception. Inside of [] you have to indicate the position of the element inside the array you want. It must be a positive number starting for 0

Answer (score 2):

single, this is due to you're performing a mathematical expression and then getting a valeu from that. meaning you're taking the length of the array list then subtracting 1 and then getting that value or in other words you're getting the last value.

to get all values you must loop like a for loop etc.

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 System.out.print(array[i]);
}
```